# Excess Space Top and Bottom of big text

Tags: css

I am working with text in C#. my problem is with big texts. In a big text I have a space at top and bottom of it.

How can I clear this space via CSS?

```
<asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Home_Club_Goal") %>' Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="200px" />
```

[image]

Comment: Reduce the space please. :)

Comment: Set the margin and padding to 0?

Comment: <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Home_Club_Goal") %>'   Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="200px" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use "line-height" property.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_line-height

Comment: i said Thanks in persian :) ... Tashakor

Comment: alah alah siz turk musiniz?   
Türkiye'yi ve turk İnsanlari seviyorum ;) 
İş için geleceğim